Transaction reverted without reason when sending ETH using MetaMask and Ethers.js, hardhat localhost network
I am developing a blockchain dApp where a customer can send ETH to a supermarket by using generated 2 d code. I'm using Solidity for the smart contract and Ethers.js for the frontend. The transaction should transfer ETH to the correct supermarket address, but it keeps reverting without any reason.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract LoyaltyPoints {
    
    struct UserProfile {
        string username;
        string role;
    }

    mapping(address => UserProfile) private profiles;
    mapping(address => uint256) private balances;
    mapping(bytes32 => PurchaseRequest) private purchaseRequests;
    event PurchaseRequestGenerated(uint256 code);

    struct PurchaseRequest {
        address supermarket;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    modifier onlyRegisteredSupermarket() {
        UserProfile memory userProfile = profiles[msg.sender];
        require(bytes(userProfile.username).length > 0, "Supermarket does not exist");
        require(keccak256(bytes(userProfile.role)) == keccak256(bytes("supermarket")), "Not a Supermarket");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyRegisteredCustomer() {
        UserProfile memory userProfile = profiles[msg.sender];
        require(bytes(userProfile.username).length > 0, "Customer does not exist");
        require(keccak256(bytes(userProfile.role)) == keccak256(bytes("customer")), "Not a Customer");
        _;
    }

    error InsufficientBalance(uint requested, uint available);

    function setProfile(string memory _username, string memory _role) public {
        profiles[msg.sender] = UserProfile(_username, _role);
    }

    function getProfile(address userAddress) public view returns (UserProfile memory) {
        return profiles[userAddress];
    }

    // Function to generate a QR code (purchase request) for a customer to scan and pay
      function generatePurchaseRequest(uint256 amount) public onlyRegisteredSupermarket returns (uint256) {
        require(amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than zero");
        uint256 code = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, amount, block.timestamp))) % 1000000; // Generate a 6-digit code
        purchaseRequests[bytes32(code)] = PurchaseRequest(msg.sender, amount);
        emit PurchaseRequestGenerated(code);
        return code;
    }
    
    // View function to get the purchase request details
function getPurchaseRequestDetails(uint256 code) public view returns (address supermarket, uint256 amount) {
    bytes32 codeHash = bytes32(code);  // Convert the code to bytes32 for lookup
    PurchaseRequest memory request = purchaseRequests[codeHash];

    // Ensure the code is valid
    require(request.supermarket != address(0), "Invalid code");
    
    return (request.supermarket, request.amount);
}

    // Function for customer to scan the QR code and pay
   function payWithCode(uint256 code,address payable supermarketAddress) public payable onlyRegisteredCustomer {
    bytes32 codeHash = bytes32(code);  // Convert the code to bytes32 for lookup
    PurchaseRequest memory request = purchaseRequests[codeHash];

    // Ensure the code is valid
    require(request.supermarket != address(0), "Invalid code");

    // Get the amount from the purchase request and ensure the customer sends the correct ETH
    uint256 amount = request.amount;
   
    // Transfer the amount to the supermarket
    balances[supermarketAddress] += amount;
    supermarketAddress.transfer(amount);

    // Remove the purchase request after payment
    delete purchaseRequests[codeHash];
}

     function sendMoneyToCustomer(address payable customer) public payable  {
       
        balances[customer] += msg.value;
        customer.transfer(msg.value);
     }
}

This is my solidity code and this is my my efrontend interacting with the contract
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { SHOPIFY_URL} from "~~/services/global.variables";

export const useShopBrandsStore = defineStore('shopBrands', {
    state: () => ({
        name: "",
        full_name: "",
       
        my_profile : null,
        contractAddress: "0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9",
        abi: [
          {
            "inputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "requested",
                "type": "uint256"
              },
              {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "available",
                "type": "uint256"
              }
            ],
            "name": "InsufficientBalance",
            "type": "error"
          },
          {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
              {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "code",
                "type": "uint256"
              }
            ],
            "name": "PurchaseRequestGenerated",
            "type": "event"
          },
          {
            "inputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
              }
            ],
            "name": "generatePurchaseRequest",
            "outputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
              }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
          },
          {
            "inputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "userAddress",
                "type": "address"
              }
            ],
            "name": "getProfile",
            "outputs": [
              {
                "components": [
                  {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "username",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "role",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                ],
                "internalType": "struct LoyaltyPoints.UserProfile",
                "name": "",
                "type": "tuple"
              }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
          },
          {
            "inputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "code",
                "type": "uint256"
              }
            ],
            "name": "getPurchaseRequestDetails",
            "outputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "supermarket",
                "type": "address"
              },
              {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
              }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
          },
          {
            "inputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "code",
                "type": "uint256"
              },
              {
                "internalType": "address payable",
                "name": "supermarketAddress",
                "type": "address"
              }
            ],
            "name": "payWithCode",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "payable",
            "type": "function"
          },
          {
            "inputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "address payable",
                "name": "customer",
                "type": "address"
              }
            ],
            "name": "sendMoneyToCustomer",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "payable",
            "type": "function"
          },
          {
            "inputs": [
              {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_username",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_role",
                "type": "string"
              }
            ],
            "name": "setProfile",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
          }
        ],
        
           
    }),
    actions: {
        async connectWallet ()  {
            console.log("Ethers:", ethers);
        
                
           const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
                console.log("Ethers:", ethers);
                console.log("Provider:", provider);
                await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);

                const signer = await provider.getSigner();
                const balance = await provider.getBalance(signer)
                const balanceInEth = ethers.formatEther(balance);
                console.log('s',this.balanceInEth)

                const walletAddress = await signer;

                // Save wallet address and provider in localStorage
               
                localStorage.setItem("signer", JSON.stringify(signer));
                return {
                  signer: signer,
                  balanceInEth: balanceInEth
              };
            
        },
        async setProfile(signer, username, role)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
            const tx = await contract.setProfile(username, role);
            await tx.wait();
        },
        async getProfile (signer)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
            console.log('signer',signer)
            const userAddress = await signer; // Get the user's wallet address
            const profile = await contract.getProfile(userAddress);
            this.my_profile = profile
            return profile;
        },
        
        
        async generatePurchaseRequest(signer, amount) {
          const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
          const txResponse = await contract.generatePurchaseRequest(amount);
        
          // Wait for the transaction to be mined
          const txReceipt = await txResponse.wait();
          
          // Now get the generated code from the transaction receipt
         
          
          const hexData = txReceipt.logs[0].data;
          console.log("txReceipt",txReceipt)
          const code = parseInt(hexData, 16);
console.log("Generated code:", code)
          return code;
      },
      // 649193
      async checkPurchaseRequest(signer, code) {
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
        
        // Retrieve purchase request details
        const [supermarket, amount] = await contract.getPurchaseRequestDetails(code);
        console.log('Supermarket:', supermarket);
        console.log('Amount:', ethers.formatEther(amount));
    
        // Now the customer can confirm the payment
        return { supermarket, amount };
    },
      //   async payWithCode(signer, code) {
      //     const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
      //     // Fetch the request
      //     const purchaseRequest = await contract.purchaseRequests(bytes32(code));
      //     console.log('p',await purchaseRequest)
      //     const ethValue = ethers.parseEther('100');
      //     // Pay with code and the corresponding amount
      //     const tx = await contract.payWithCode(code , {value: ethValue}// Ensure to send the correct ETH amount
      //     );
      //     await tx.wait(); // Wait for the transaction to be mined
      //     console.log('Payment successful:', tx);
      // },
       
      async payWithCode(signer, code) {
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
        
        // Fetch the request details first
        const { supermarket, amount } = await this.checkPurchaseRequest(signer, code);
    
        // Proceed with the payment
        console.log('address of supermarket',supermarket)
        const my_amount = ethers.parseEther(amount.toString())
        console.log('my_account',my_amount)
        const tx = await contract.payWithCode(code,supermarket,{ value: my_amount });
        await tx.wait(); // Wait for the transaction to be mined
        console.log('Payment successful:', tx);
    },
        async sendMoneyToCustomer  (signer,customerAddress,amount)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);

         
            console.log('ETH Amount:', amount);
            console.log('aaa',customerAddress)
            const ethValue = ethers.parseEther(amount);
            console.log('ETH in Wei:', ethValue);
            const tx = await contract.sendMoneyToCustomer(customerAddress, {value: ethValue},  // Convert the amount from ETH to Wei
            );
            console.log('tx',tx)
            await tx.wait();  // Wait for the transaction to be mined
        },
        
        // Whenever I use the payable function the transaction is reverted, saying reverted for no reason 
      
    }
});

I am interacting with the contract but all other function are working expect those payable they are reverting transaction

Solidity code looks good. Please check in ethers.js code and make sure you are providing enough gas?
